# Weird java memory allocation

Tags: lubuntu, java, memory-usage

My task manager shows that for my java process memory allocated is 16777216.0 TB (yep, TB).
It happens when programming swing application  with eclipse 3.8.
Oh, and my distro is lubuntu 14.04. Nothing special about it, just regular install.

Running eclipse with -xmx512 doesn't help, really. Any ideas because I don't even know where to start looking.

Comment: That's 2^24 TB, which, if you convert it down to bytes (using 1024 bytes=1 MB), would be 2^64 bytes, so this could be a case of integer overflow in the task manager. In Terminal, if you run `ps aux | grep eclipse`, there is (hopefully) a line about eclipse itself. What does the 6th entry in the column say? If you're unsure, paste the line here.